# Specified cast not valid error shows on aspx gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I get this error on this column in a `gridview' :-

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='<%# Eval("url") %>' target="_blank" style="color:#330000; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold"><%# Eval("title") %></a>
                    <br />
                    <p  runat="server" id="description"><%# Eval("des") %></p>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="click_like" runat="server" ImageUrl= "~/pics/like.png" Height="20px" CommandName="like" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' BorderStyle="Outset" BorderColor="#99CCFF" Enabled='<%# Eval("like_enabled") %>' />&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_like" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("like") %>'></asp:Label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="click_dislike" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/pics/dislike.png" Height="20px" CommandName="dislike" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' BorderStyle="Outset" BorderColor="#99CCFF" Enabled='<%# Eval("dislike_enabled") %>'/>&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_dislike" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dislike") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <p runat="server" id="labels"><%# Eval("labels") %></p>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I get this error on the line:-

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="click_like" runat="server" ImageUrl= "~/pics/like.png" Height="20px" CommandName="like" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' BorderStyle="Outset" BorderColor="#99CCFF" Enabled='<%# Eval("like_enabled") %>' />&nbsp;
```

And I get this because I am binding the value of `Enabled` attribute from a `DataTable` where `like_enabled` column is either "true" or "false"

Comment: I see two mentions of `this error`, but never actually see it. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to bind `Enabled` like that, you'll have to use an `RowDataBound` event:

```
<asp:GridView id="myGrid" OnRowDataBound="myGrid_RowDatabound">
```

Code behind:

```
public void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var enabled = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "like_enabled");
        var click_like = e.Row.FindControl("click_like") as ImageButton;
        click_like.Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives error :- cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: @SohamKrishna check my edit. You'll have to use an `RowDataBound` event.